# Matrix manipulation using trace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose that $u$ is an $N\times 1$ random vector and $M$ is an $N\times N$ nonrandom positive semi-definite matrix that is also idempotent: $M\times M=M$.

**Claim**: $E(u'Muu'Mu)=\text{Tr}\{M E[(u'Mu)uu']\}$.

Attempt: because $u'Muu'Mu$ is scalar, we have
$$
E(u'Muu'Mu)=E[\text{Tr}(u'Muu'Mu)]
$$
then I'm pretty sure I'm supposed to use $\text{Tr}(AB)=\text{Tr}(BA)$ somehow and then switch the order of $E$ and $\text{Tr}$. But I can't make it work. Could someone please lend a hand?

It is also given that $E(u)=0$ and $E(uu')=\sigma^2 I$ but I don't think this is relevant.

Comment: What is $E$ here?

Comment: @ Travis: taking expectation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the idempotence or positive semidefiniteness of $M$.

$\alpha = u'Mu$ is a scalar. Therefore $u'Muu'Mu=\alpha u'Mu=\operatorname{tr}(u'M\alpha u)$ and in turn
$$
E(u'Muu'Mu)
=E(\operatorname{tr}(u'M\alpha u))
=E(\operatorname{tr}(M\alpha uu'))
=\operatorname{tr}(E(M\alpha uu'))
=\operatorname{tr}(ME(\alpha uu')).
$$